# Consumir Web Service desde SQL

Tags: sql-server, webservice, stored-procedure, soap

Tengo mi `WS` echo `PHP` con `SOAP` el ejemplo lo encontré en: [WS EJEMPLO](http://www.mauricioalpizar.com/ejemplo-de-como-programar-un-web-service-utilizando-nusoap-y-php/)
y para consumir dicho `WS` ahí viene una descripción y todo eso me funciona perfecto en `PHP`, ahora lo que intento hacer es consumir dicho `WS` pero desde un procedimiento de `SQL Server` pero me maca error de `parseo` al enviar los datos no se que estoy haciendo mal:

// Código SP

```
CREATE PROCEDURE [dbo].[sp_enviarCorreoEjmp] 
    -- Add the parameters for the stored procedure here

AS
BEGIN
    DECLARE @authHeader NVARCHAR(64);
DECLARE @contentType NVARCHAR(64);
DECLARE @postData NVARCHAR(2000);
DECLARE @responseText NVARCHAR(2000);
DECLARE @responseXML NVARCHAR(2000);
DECLARE @ret INT;
DECLARE @status NVARCHAR(32);
DECLARE @statusText NVARCHAR(32);
DECLARE @token INT;
DECLARE @url NVARCHAR(256);

SET @authHeader = 'BASIC 0123456789ABCDEF0123456789ABCDEF';
SET @contentType = 'application/x-www-form-urlencoded';
SET @postData = '{
            emisor : prueba@midominio.com,
            contrasenia : 15478e,
            host : mail.midominio.com,
            puertoEnvio : 465,
            destinatarios : prueba@midominio.com,
            asunto : PRUEBA BD,
            cuerpo : BD
      }'
SET @url = 'http://localhost/CorreoSuite/enviarCorreo_WS.php'

-- Open the connection.
--EXEC @ret = sp_OACreate 'MSXML2.ServerXMLHTTP', @token OUT;
--IF @ret <> 0 RAISERROR('Unable to open HTTP connection.', 10, 1);

-- Send the request.

EXEC sp_OACreate 'MSXML2.ServerXMLHttp', @token OUT
EXEC sp_OAMethod @token, 'Open', NULL, 'post', @url, false
EXEC sp_OAMethod @token, 'setRequestHeader', NULL, 'Content-Type', 'text/xml;charset=UTF-8'
EXEC sp_OAMethod @token, 'setRequestHeader', NULL, 'SOAPAction', 'POST'
--EXEC sp_OAMethod @obj, 'setRequestHeader', NULL, 'Content-Length', LEN(@requestBody)
EXEC sp_OAMethod @token, 'send', NULL, @postData
EXEC sp_OAGetProperty @token, 'responseText', @postData OUT


SELECT @postData [RESPONSE]

EXEC sp_OADestroy @token

END
```

Al ejecuta dicho SP

```
exec sp_enviarCorreoEjmp
```

me muestra el siguiente error:

```
    <SOAP-ENV:Body><SOAP-ENV:Fault><faultcode xsi:type="xsd:string">SOAP-ENV:Client</faultcode><faultactor xsi:type="xsd:string"></faultactor><faultstring xsi:type="xsd:string">error in msg parsing:
{
            emisor : prueba@midominio.com,
            contrasenia : 15478e,
            host : mail.midominio.com,
            puertoEnvio : 465,
            destinatarios : prueba@midominio.com
            asunto : PRUEBA BD,
            cuerpo : BD
      }</faultstring><detail xsi:type="xsd:string"></detail></SOAP-ENV:Fault></SOAP-ENV:Body></SOAP-ENV:Envelope>


XML error parsing SOAP payload on line 1: Not well-formed (invalid token)
```